# Help me understand this part from the book "Long Way Down"

Tags: phrases, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, meaning

What does **"So I explained them to her so she wouldn’t think less of me for following them like was just another block boy on one looking to off one."** in the following free verse poem mean?

```
DANI WAS KILLED

before she ever learned
The Rules.

So I explained them to
her so she wouldn’t think
less of me for following
them

like I was just another
block boy on one
looking to off one.

So that she knew I had
purpose

and that this was about
family

and had I known
The Rules when we
were kids I would’ve
done the same thing

for her.
```

-from Long Way Down by Jason Reynolds, pub Simon & Schuster 2017

Comment: As a Brit, I understand *to be "on one"* as the BrE colloquial usage [*to be/go **off on one***](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/off-on-one) (to rant agitatedly). But I'm guessing a "block boy" is the modern equivalent of *a boy from the 'hood (neighbourhood, a local boy)* - primarily an American AAVE usage. And *to "off" someone* is "gansta" slang for *to **kill** someone*, both sides of the pond. There may be some kind of wordplay associating / juxtaposing ***block*** with ***black***, I dunno. But it's lyrics / poetry, so not really On Topic for this site.

Answer (score 1):

**another block boy on one** is confusing but means **another typical boy who lives on the block of houses.**

**looking to off one** means **wanting to kill someone**

So if you rephrased the section:

---

Original: "So I explained them to
her so she wouldn’t think
less of me for following
them like I was just another
block boy on one
looking to off one."

Rephrasing: "I explained the Rules to Dani so she would not think badly of me for following them. I didn't want her to think of me as just another boy living in the neighbourhood (block) who is eager to kill someone."

---

Wider context reveals that Dani is the ghost of a girl who was killed in an accidental shooting and so could not have known the rules and ways of the neighbourhood (the block). The Rules demand revenge killings and not showing emotions. The protagonist Will is being challenged by the dead as he is considering or preparing to shoot someone.

It's not entirely clear if the ghosts are supernatural manifestations or just his imagination or subconscious.